# ConnectionError: Python while using requests.Session().send(my_request_here)

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to make a POST call.

While executing this statement `requests.Session().send(my_request_here)`

This is the stack trace which I am getting

```
/Users/myname/Documents/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.pyc in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

/Users/myname/Documents/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.pyc in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
--> 516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    517 
    518         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mydomanin.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: 'myendpoint' (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mydomain.net', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)",))
```

I am sending all headers correctly.

Comment: the url is not accessible. Requests is trying to reach but it's not able to reach the website

Comment: @bigbounty But when I am trying to hit the same endpoint through Postman it is executing successfully.

Comment: Are you using `ssl`? If yes try giving `verify=False` in the send method

Comment: @bigbounty....assigning verify as True or False I am getting error.

Comment: Seems like it can not find the site. Are you creating the session properly?

Comment: using urllib3 resolved the issue.